# Error compiling ZBar example in Windows: Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, imagemagick, zbar

I've [downloaded ZBar-0.1](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html), and I'm trying to compile the example project - `c:\Program Files (x86)\ZBar\examples\scan_image.vcproj`.

However it's giving me this error:

```
scan_image.cpp(2) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h': No such file or directory
```

In the project settings, I see this include path in "Additional Include Directories" - `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.4-Q16\include`.

I downloaded and ran the installer for ImageMagick, but it didn't install an "include" directory:

[image]

How do I install ImageMagick in such a way that the ZBar example can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-run the installer, and be sure to check the option that installs development libraries & headers.

[image: Install development headers and libraries for C and C++]

Comment: Thank you. This steered me in the right direction. The installer I had downloaded - `ImageMagick-6.9.2-4-Q16-x64-static.exe` - didn't have that checkbox at all, but I tried with `ImageMagick-6.9.2-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe` and it had it.

Comment: I had another mistake - I got `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`, and it was because my ZBar example was 32-bit, so I needed to download the 32-bit ImageMagick - `ImageMagick-6.9.2-4-Q16-x86-static.exe`.